# How to render a water simulation with camera tracking keyframes?

Tags: rendering, animation, physics

I have created a water simulation comming out of a modelled water fountain sprout. I want to create a rendered scene shot from the viewpoint of a camera revolving around the fountain, by using key frames in blender 2.8. However only the water sim ends up getting rendered, and the key frame animations are ignored in both preview and baked and rendered outputs.
Does anyone know if it is possible to do what I am trying to achive, and how to go about it please?

Comment: What do your keyframes control? What do you mean the water gets rendered, but the keyframes don't?

Comment: When you play the animation in the viewport and look through the camera, is the motion correct?

Comment: No it isn't and subsequently thanks for letting me see my error. I forgot to select the camera object first before applying the keyframest, i mistakenly applied keyframes to the cube object instead, which is why i got the impression that the camera animation wasnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the common beginners error of forgetting to activate the object you want to key frame first before actually key framing.